# How to draw flat topped hex (title) image in PHP?

Tags: php, image, drawing

I am trying to draw a hex using PHP. I have been trying to follow the manual from  http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/ supporting myself with leland hex generation class (https://github.com/pushcx/leland/blob/master/class_hex_image.php).

Unluckily my "hex" looks like this:

[image]

Can you please advice what am I doing wrong or tell me how can I create a proper hex?

It seems to me that function which grabs hex corners does not work correctly:

```
  function hex_corners($center, $size)
    {
        $points = array();
        for($i=0; $i <= 5; $i++)
        {
            $deg = 60 * $i; // Oblicz kąt, w którym znajduje sie róg hexu
            $rad = pi() / 180 * $deg; // Przelicz kąt na radiany
            $points[$i] = array_push($points, $center['x'] + $this->size / 2 * cos($rad), $center['y'] + $this->size / 2 * sin($rad)); 
        }
        return($points);
    }
```

but I have tried to mimic the one described in http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/ manual:

```
function hex_corner(center, size, i):
    var angle_deg = 60 * i  
    var angle_rad = PI / 180 * angle_deg
    return Point(center.x + size * cos(angle_rad),
                 center.y + size * sin(angle_rad))
```

I am using the following draw function:

```
public function hex_draw($x, $y)
    {
        $this->hex = imagecreatetruecolor ($this->size , $this->size);
        $center['x'] = $this->size / 2;
        $center['y'] = $this->size / 2;
        $blue = imagecolorallocate($this->hex, 0, 0, 255);
        // Get points
        $points = $this->hex_corners($center, $this->size);
        //die($print_r($points);
        imagefilledpolygon($this->hex, $points, count($points)/2,  $blue);
        // flush image
        header('Content-type: image/png');
        imagepng($this->hex);   
        imagedestroy($this->hex);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was trivial.

In line

```
 $points[$i] = array_push($points, $center['x'] + $this->size / 2 * cos($rad), $center['y'] + $this->size / 2 * sin($rad));
```

there was unneeded `[$i]` which caused problems.

Hex may be properly generated using the following code:

```
<?php

class hexmapimage
{

    private $size = 100;
    private $hex;

    public function hex_draw($x, $y)
    {
        $this->hex = imagecreatetruecolor ($this->size , $this->size);
        $center['x'] = $this->size / 2;
        $center['y'] = $this->size / 2;
        $black = imagecolorallocate($this->hex, 0, 0, 0);
        $blue = imagecolorallocate($this->hex, 0, 0, 255);
        $transparent =  imagecolortransparent ($this->hex, $black);
        // Get points
        $points = $this->hex_corners($center, $this->size);
        imagefilledrectangle($this->hex, 0, 0, $this->size, $this->size, $transparent);
        imagefilledpolygon($this->hex, $points, count($points)/2,  $blue);
        // flush image
        header('Content-type: image/png');
        imagepng($this->hex);   
        imagedestroy($this->hex);
    }   

    /*
    * $center = array(x coordinate of center of hex, y coordinate of center of hex)
    * $size = int (size of hex)
    */
    function hex_corners($center, $size)
    {
        $points = array();
        for($i=0; $i <= 5; $i++)
        {
            $deg = 60 * $i; // Oblicz kąt, w którym znajduje sie róg hexu
            $rad = deg2rad($deg); // Przelicz kąt na radiany
            array_push($points, $center['x'] + $this->size / 2 * cos($rad), $center['y'] + $this->size / 2 * sin($rad)); 
        }
        return($points);
    }
}

$hex = new hexmapimage();
$hex->hex_draw(0, 0);
```